# Is kde5 backwards compatible with apps/widgets/themes from kde4?

Tags: compatibility, kde4, kde5

Basically everything is said in the title. I'm thinking of trying kde5 but before I go through fixing my package system and dealing with a new DE, I want to know if I can use any of the themes/effects/widgets/apps and such from kde4 (I've spent probably about 20-25 hours at the very least getting my KDE settings and such to where they are now on my laptop, and don't want to have to deal with a bunch of permission issues rolling back to kde4 on my desktop and copying back the configuration files and such.)